# Rails elasticsearch Mappings are ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch

So I have been trying to make this work for few hours now, nothing seems to work.

I have `mappings` defined in my model:

```
  settings do
    mappings dynamic: false do
      indexes :title, type: 'text'
      indexes :description, type: 'text'
      indexes :user, type: 'text' do
        indexes :name, type: 'text'
      end
    end
  end
```

But when I do:

`Podcast.__elasticsearch__.delete_index! force: true`
`Podcast.__elasticsearch__.create_index! force: true`
`Podcast.__elasticsearch__.import force: true`

and visit: `http://localhost:9200/podcasts/_search?pretty=true&q=*:*&size=1000`

I see all of the model data poured into the indexes(I need only title, description and user name).

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When indexing, rails-ealsticsearch uses `as_indexed_json`. Here's my example:

```
def as_indexed_json(options = {})
  as_json(include: {
    user: {
      only: [
        :id,
        :slug, 
        :name
      ]
    }
  })
end
```